# Facebook ads api : how to get photo_id for creating canvas photo

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In facebook ads api, i want to create an instant experience. So i'm creating the Instant Experience image as a first step (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/collection/)

So i got id of the image uploaded in the ad account gallery for creating canvas photo.

```
canvas_photo={ 
     "photo_id": $photo_id, // id of the image 
}
```

But that's giving me an error

**(#100) Param canvas_photo[photo_id] must be a valid photo id **

Please guide me how to get a PHOTO_ID for creating canvas photo

Comment: Have you tried separately creating a photo and using the ID from the response? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/#Creating

Comment: Yes i tried the id of ad media gallery image but that's not working then i tried with page photo id then it worked

Comment: Good, is your problem solved then?

Comment: In my case i have around 300 ads to be created and each ad has different pages. So there's a process to create a photo in page like i need to get a page access_token then i need to create a photo in page but i shouldn't post it in page timeline, i was looking to use image_hash of image from ad media gallery. looks like that's not possible thing :(